# How do I get a brave.Tracing from a micrometer Tracer?

Tags: java, spring, redis, distributed-tracing

I want to add Redis tracing into Lettuce which only supports Brave from what I can tell.

So I want to get this code

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
fun lettuceClientResources(): ClientResources {

    return DefaultClientResources.builder()
        .tracing(BraveTracing.create(**NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE**))
        .build()
}
```

I tried

- `Tracing.current()`
- Injecting a `brave.Tracing` doesn't exist

Comment: you want to integrate Lettuce with Brave via the `BraveTracing` right ?

Comment: This is the only one I found that talks about it https://www.changchao.me/?p=941

Answer (score 0):

Just searched around the source code and found another class that does what I needed

```kotlin
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
fun lettuceClientResources(observationRegistry: ObservationRegistry): ClientResources = DefaultClientResources.builder()
  .tracing(MicrometerTracingAdapter(observationRegistry, "redis"))
  .build()
```